# Find recursively the third biggest element of array in c

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

This one was asked in one of my computer science exam months has passed but I couldn't find any answers.Sometimes I wonder if its possible or not here is the prototype.

The objective is to return the index of third largest element in an integer array.I have learned how to find the largest and second largest but this seems hard.

```
int third_max(int arr[],int size);
```

I am looking a recursive function that will find it by maybe only one functions help that is max(a,b) which returns the max of a,b.
Edit : There is no duplicate elements

Comment: Why do you think that finding the third-largest element is harder (or even particularly different) from finding the second-largest element? Perhaps you could write a better question by providing your solution for second-largest and precisely describe the difficulty you have in generalising it.

Comment: There's a [Quick Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm analogous to Quick Sort that can be used for the task.  It doesn't sort the whole array.

Comment: Call `int third_max_helper(int arr[],int size, int *third, int *second, int *first);` of both _halves_ of the array and integrate results.

Comment: Yes I could also replace the max elements with other values twice then the max would be my answer but then this function won't be recursive .I am looking a recursive function that will find it by maybe only one functions help(max(a,b)).

Comment: Why not just sort the array in ascending and return the third from last element? You'd probably need to account for repeated integers, though. I believe that's what TypeIA is referring to.

Comment: @selman: your question  simply is not clear nor specific enough to attract good answers, which is why you aren't getting any. I reiterate the suggestion in my first comment.

Comment: If the array has duplicate values, say `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 }` are the largest three values `3`, `4` and `4`? Or are they `2`, `3` and `4`?

Comment: I have updated the rules

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of `third_max()`.  (It uses an `assert` to catch a starting array shorter than three elements.) First it sorts the first three elements in the array in place; if the array is only three elements long, it returns the first.  If the array is more than three elements, it compares the first and forth elements, keeping the larger as the fourth element.  Finally, it calls it self recursively dropping off the first array element and decrimenting the array size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE (10)

int third_max(int array[], size_t size) {
    assert(size > 2);

    if (array[0] > array[1]) {
        int temp = array[1];
        array[1] = array[0];
        array[0] = temp;
    }

    if (array[1] > array[2]) {
        int temp = array[2];
        array[2] = array[1];
        array[1] = temp;
    }

    if (array[0] > array[1]) {
        int temp = array[1];
        array[1] = array[0];
        array[0] = temp;
    }

    if (size == 3) {
        return array[0];
    }

    if (array[0] > array[3]) {
        array[3] = array[0];
    }

    return third_max(array + 1, size - 1);
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return (*aa > *bb) - (*aa < *bb);
}

int main() {
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE], control[ARRAY_SIZE];

    srandomdev();

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {

        int x = -1;

        while (x == -1) {

            x = (random() & 127) - 63;

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] == x) { // avoid duplicates
                    x = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        control[i] = array[i] = x;
    }

    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("] -> ");

    printf("%d ", third_max(array, ARRAY_SIZE));

    qsort(control, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(int), &compare);

    printf("(%d)\n", control[ARRAY_SIZE - 3]);

    return 1;
}
```

The rest of the code tests the `third_max()` function by creating an array of unique positive integers.  It compares the results of the recursive function to that of a matching control array that is sorted and the third to last element extracted for comparison.

My `third_max()` doesn't call any other functions other than itself (i.e. no *helper* functions.)  It is destructive on the array passed in.

Answer (score -1):

Without any additional constraints, a naive but effective solution would simply be to create a sorted copy of the array, take the third element, then find that element in the original array and return its index. The theoretical complexity is O(n log n) in time and O(n) in space. An O(n) time solution is possible.